# Cannot open Bootstrap modal in React

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

The modal-backdrop div gets added but I am not able to see the modal dilog.
Below is the code of my react component:

```
var OpenModal = React.createClass({


render: function(){


return(

    <div>

     <button type="button" className="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>


<div className="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div className="modal-dialog">


  <div className="modal-content">
    <div className="modal-header">
      <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 className="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div className="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the modal.<br/>
    fnfgjdg<br/>
    sbdfbsdfbdfbdfb<br/>
    fgdnbndbgdbfdvfgnfbfb<br/>
    gnbvvghfnbvhfnb<br/>
    </p>
    </div>
    <div className="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
 </div>

    </div>



)



 }


});

module.exports = OpenModal;
```

I just want to open a bootstrap modal in React. If anyone has any other working sample that would help but not using react bootstrap.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what the problem is ? Your modal should open when clicked on the first button.

Comment: Do you see errors in the Browser Console? Your Component seems correct so far, but the question is if everything is wired up properly. A bit more context would be helpful. I just dumped [your code into a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/lekejayeqe/1/edit?html,js,output) and it works fine. Maybe that helps already.

Comment: try using react-bootstrap

Comment: thanks @MarcelFahle used the code which you dumped in JSBin it worked.